# stanford-nlp How to predict document level

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am using stanford-corenlp-3.4.1 version. I have the question if we give the sentence has multiple sentence, how do I calculate the prediction.

for eg :
String text = "IT was very fantastic experience. it was a pathetice experience";

i am getting the prediction of

IT was very fantastic experience : positive.

it was a pathetice experience : negative.

i  am getting the prediction based on each sentence level.how do i get it document level.

based on reading the total text i need to get it either positive or negative.

Here is the sample code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment");

        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation("IT was very fantastic experience. it was a pathetice experience");
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
          String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName.class);
          System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentence);

    }
```

Results:

Very positive:  IT was very fantastic experience.
Negative    it was a pathetice experience

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Stanford NLP does not provide sentiment analysis above the sentence level. One solution would be to compute some sort of mean sentiment value across all sentences in your text, but obviously that's only going to give you a rough idea of the overall sentiment.

Comment: i think we are going to come up with our own algorithm to determine it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @VinojMathew, did you come up with the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Yvespeirsman is on the right track. You can compute an average for a term across the entire document. If you break up the entire document into sentences then calculated sentiment per sentence and compute an average this should give you a good idea of the sentiment regarding that term across the entire studied docum

We made an implementation of his with source code viewable: https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/nlp/SentimentByTerm